# Chart in d3js not showing up in react app

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to follow the tutorial [here](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/pie_changeData.html) but using react app.   The chart is not showing up and I am not sure what I am doing wrong, please help.  I am using d3 v7 and react 17.  I get no errors but the buttons show up so the component is called correctly.

This is my component:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'
import * as React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react'

const PieChart = (props) => {
    const ref = React.createRef()
    useEffect(() => {
      draw()
    });

    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    const width = 450, height = 450, margin = 40;
    // The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.
    const radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin;
    // set the color scale
    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"])
    .range(d3.schemeDark2);
    // create 2 data_set
    const data1 = {a: 9, b: 20, c:30, d:8, e:12}
    const data2 = {a: 6, b: 16, c:20, d:14, e:19, f:12}
    const svg = d3.select(".PieChart")


    // A function that create / update the plot for a given variable:
    const update = (data) => {
        if (data == "data1"){
            data = data1;
        }else{
            data = data2;
        }

        // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
        const pie = d3.pie()
        .value(function(d) {return d[1]; })
        .sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.key, b.key);} ) // This make sure that group order remains the same in the pie chart
        const data_ready = pie(Object.entries(data))

        // map to data
        const u = svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(data_ready)

        // Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
        u
        .join('path')
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr('d', d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(0)
        .outerRadius(radius)
        )
        .attr('fill', function(d){ return(color(d.data[0])) })
        .attr("stroke", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
        .style("opacity", 1)

    }
    
    const draw = () => {

        svg.append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${width/2}, ${height/2})`);


        // Initialize the plot with the first dataset
        update("data1")
    };
    

    return <div ref={ref} >
            <button onClick={update("data1")}>Data 1</button>
            <button onClick={update("data2")}>Data 2</button> 
            <div className="PieChart" /> 
        </div>
}

export default PieChart
```

This is what I get, no graph

[image]

Comment: Did you inspect the DOM to see that it wasn't there?

Comment: There isn't a question in this post

Comment: oh you are right it's there in DOM, so I guess it works?  But I don't see it though as shown in the screenshot, how come it's not showing up?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are quite a few things that need to be fixed.
First & foremost is the usage of `ref`. You have to do `const ref = React.useRef()` i.e use `useRef` instead of `createRef`.
Also, the ref has to be set to the `svg` element and not the `div`.

The 'almost' working code is here. https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-heisenberg-vppny?file=/src/pie.js

I say almost because the chart does not render on page load! I do not know why (I am not very familiar with react). To render the chart, change the value of `width` or `height` from 450 to 451. I do not know why this works but it does.

One the page is loaded with the chart, the buttons & the chart transition work fine.

If you figure how to render the chart on page load, please let me know.

Comment: hey dude, it's all good, I got around it by using a different tutorial

Comment: can you share the solution you found? I can also learn from that.